# Quadtree realization c++ (by Quad)

Tags: c++, opengl, quadtree

I'am using quadtree in 2D coordinates (base code get here: https://github.com/veeableful/Quadtree_Minimal)

At start, code using just one point to detect rectangles inside quadtree.
But detecting object is quad - select rectagles from quadtree become more complex. First decision was: detect rectangles form quadtree by 4 points, then sort them and remove duplicates. But question is - how good is this realization? Maybe there is more fast/optimized ways?

Rectangle:

```
struct stRectangle
{
    float p[2]; //start point x/y
    float s[2]; //width/height
};
```

Quad:

```
struct stQuad
{
  glm::vec2 p[4];
};
```

Detecting by point:

```
vector<stRectangle*> MQuadTree::GetRectanglesAt(float inX, float inY)
{
    if(Level == MaxLevel) return Rectangles;

    vector<stRectangle*> ReturnRectangles, ChildReturnRectangles;
    if(!Rectangles.empty()) ReturnRectangles = Rectangles;

    const float HalfWidth = Width * 0.5;
    const float HalfHeight = Height * 0.5;

    if(inX > X + HalfWidth && inX < X + Width)
    {
        if(inY > Y + HalfHeight && inY < Y + Height)
        {
            ChildReturnRectangles = SE->GetRectanglesAt(inX, inY);
            ReturnRectangles.insert(ReturnRectangles.begin(), ChildReturnRectangles.begin(), ChildReturnRectangles.end());
            return ReturnRectangles;
        }
        if(inY > Y && inY <= Y + HalfHeight)
        {
            ChildReturnRectangles = NE->GetRectanglesAt(inX, inY);
            ReturnRectangles.insert(ReturnRectangles.begin(), ChildReturnRectangles.begin(), ChildReturnRectangles.end());
            return ReturnRectangles;
        }
    }
    if(inX > X && inX <= X + HalfWidth)
    {
        if(inY > Y + HalfHeight && inY < Y + Height)
        {
            ChildReturnRectangles = SW->GetRectanglesAt(inX, inY);
            ReturnRectangles.insert(ReturnRectangles.begin(), ChildReturnRectangles.begin(), ChildReturnRectangles.end());
            return ReturnRectangles;
        }
        if(inY > Y && inY <= Y + HalfHeight)
        {
            ChildReturnRectangles = NW->GetRectanglesAt(inX, inY);
            ReturnRectangles.insert(ReturnRectangles.begin(), ChildReturnRectangles.begin(), ChildReturnRectangles.end());
            return ReturnRectangles;
        }
    }
    return ReturnRectangles;
}
```

**Detecting by Quad (suspicious code)**:

```
vector<stRectangle*> MQuadTree::GetRectanglesAt(float* Points)
{
    vector<stRectangle*> ReturnRectangles;
    vector<stRectangle*> CurrentRectangles;
    CurrentRectangles = GetRectanglesAt(*(Points + 0), *(Points + 1));
    ReturnRectangles.insert(ReturnRectangles.end(), CurrentRectangles.begin(), CurrentRectangles.end());
    CurrentRectangles = GetRectanglesAt(*(Points + 2), *(Points + 3));
    ReturnRectangles.insert(ReturnRectangles.end(), CurrentRectangles.begin(), CurrentRectangles.end());
    CurrentRectangles = GetRectanglesAt(*(Points + 4), *(Points + 5));
    ReturnRectangles.insert(ReturnRectangles.end(), CurrentRectangles.begin(), CurrentRectangles.end());
    CurrentRectangles = GetRectanglesAt(*(Points + 6), *(Points + 7));
    ReturnRectangles.insert(ReturnRectangles.end(), CurrentRectangles.begin(), CurrentRectangles.end());
    sort(ReturnRectangles.begin(), ReturnRectangles.end());
    ReturnRectangles.erase(unique(ReturnRectangles.begin(), ReturnRectangles.end()), ReturnRectangles.end());

    return ReturnRectangles;
}
```

Buttons processing:

```
void MGame2::OnKeyDown(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    Key[wParam] = 1;
    if(pDrawFunc == &MGame2::DrawGame)
    {
        if(Key[VK_ESCAPE])
        {
            SendMessage(m_hWnd, WM_DESTROY, 0, 0);
            return;
        }
        if(!Pause)
        {
            if(Key[VK_LEFT]) MoveQuad(PointQuad, -5, 0);
            if(Key[VK_RIGHT]) MoveQuad(PointQuad, 5, 0);
            if(Key[VK_UP]) MoveQuad(PointQuad, 0, 5);
            if(Key[VK_DOWN]) MoveQuad(PointQuad, 0, -5);
            if(Key[VK_LEFT] || Key[VK_RIGHT] || Key[VK_UP] || Key[VK_DOWN])
            {
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vtxPointQuadId);
                glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec2) * 4, &PointQuad.p[0][0], GL_STREAM_DRAW);
                NearRectanglesToBuffer(PointQuad);
                if(TestCollisions()) SetPointQuadColor(1, 0, 0, 1); else SetPointQuadColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Quadtree view]

Comment: If you just want something that works then consider using [boost's rtree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree.html).

Comment: @PaulR Thanks. Will try to use boost c++ libraries.